# Elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

I'd like to know what is the maximum bits of the finite field that we can solve the ECDLP in a "regular" computer in trivial time. Is there any recent data about this?

Comment: Regular computer time is not clear. Which CPU? which GPU? Maybe you are asking about secure field size? See [BlueKrypt](https://www.keylength.com/), also known as keylength.com.

Comment: Any reason the information on Wikipedia [Discrete logarithm records: Elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records#Elliptic_curves) doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @kelalaka: Why is there such a difference bewteen methods if we select a distant year i.e year 2040? ECRYPT recommends a 15k bit modulus the rest of methods stick to 2-3k bits modulus size. I'm surprised it doesn't include any estimation method for non-conventional crypto (non-commutative, lattice, codes, multivariate etc).

Comment: @kub0x Different measures and predictions. There are links on the below of the table for the bibliography.